# cp matching files in CLI on OSX with path slightly modified

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, file-transfer

I am trying to find a command that finds and copies files with a given name to a another folder but with a slightly different path.

For e.g. there are 4 copies of PNG files named `ic_arrow.png`

```
app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_arrow.png
app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_arrow.png
app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_arrow.png
app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_arrow.png
```

and I would like to copy this to

```
feature/name1/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_arrow.png
feature/name1/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_arrow.png
feature/name1/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_arrow.png
feature/name1/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_arrow.png
```

i.e. the right dpi version of the found file gets copied to the right dpi version of the target directory

does anyone know how I can do this with the find command or a script etc?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rsync way:

```
rsync -avh --include="*/" --include="*.png" --exclude="*" app/ feature/name1/
```

---

**Testing it:**

```
mkdir -p app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/
touch app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_arrow.png app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_arrow.png app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_arrow.png app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_arrow.png
mkdir -p feature/name1/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ feature/name1/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ feature/name1/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ feature/name1/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/
```

tree app

```
app/
└── src
    └── main
        └── res
            ├── drawable-hdpi
            │   └── ic_arrow.png
            ├── drawable-mdpi
            │   └── ic_arrow.png
            ├── drawable-xhdpi
            │   └── ic_arrow.png
            └── drawable-xxhdpi
                └── ic_arrow.png
```

tree feature

```
feature/
└── name1
    └── src
        └── main
            └── res
                ├── drawable-hdpi
                ├── drawable-mdpi
                ├── drawable-xhdpi
                └── drawable-xxhdpi
```

rsync command

```
rsync -avh --include="*/" --include="*.png" --exclude="*" app/ feature/name1/
```

Final result (tree feature)

```
feature/
└── name1
    └── src
        └── main
            └── res
                ├── drawable-hdpi
                │   └── ic_arrow.png
                ├── drawable-mdpi
                │   └── ic_arrow.png
                ├── drawable-xhdpi
                │   └── ic_arrow.png
                └── drawable-xxhdpi
                    └── ic_arrow.png
```